# AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qmainwindow

I am still working on the GUI for my Database and now i have a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\Database Kast Thuis\PyQt Test\MainMenu_ui.py", line 84, in <module>
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
  File "G:\Python\Database Kast Thuis\PyQt Test\MainMenu_ui.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "G:\Python\Database Kast Thuis\PyQt Test\MainMenu_ui.py", line 55, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

I dont understand a thing about PyQt so i dont understand what the problem is.

The code is:
(This is the edited version, Raw Version is Posted below)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Main_Menu.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(387, 317)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/Natan Samuel Geldorp.Remytop-PC/Documents/music-note-sound-256.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.ButtonRemove = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonRemove.setObjectName("ButtonRemove")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonRemove, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonShowAll = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonShowAll.setObjectName("ButtonShowAll")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonShowAll, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonShowSpecific = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonShowSpecific.setObjectName("ButtonShowSpecific")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonShowSpecific, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Text.setObjectName("Text")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Text, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonAdd.setObjectName("ButtonAdd")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonAdd, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonExit.setObjectName("ButtonExit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonExit, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.ButtonRemove.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Remove an album"))
        self.ButtonShowAll.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show all registerd albums"))
        self.ButtonShowSpecific.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show a specific album"))
        self.Text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome to the MusicDatabase Version 2.1-2017"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please select one of the options below."))
        self.ButtonAdd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add an album"))
        self.ButtonExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Authors: N.S. Geldorp & H. Nahumury"))
        self.ButtonExit.clicked.connect(self.ButtonExit)

    def ButtonExit(self):
        exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone see the problem?

-Natan

Posting Raw Convert:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Main_Menu.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(387, 317)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/Natan Samuel Geldorp.Remytop-PC/Documents/music-note-sound-256.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.ButtonRemove = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonRemove.setObjectName("ButtonRemove")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonRemove, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonShowAll = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonShowAll.setObjectName("ButtonShowAll")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonShowAll, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonShowSpecific = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonShowSpecific.setObjectName("ButtonShowSpecific")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonShowSpecific, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Text.setObjectName("Text")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Text, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonAdd.setObjectName("ButtonAdd")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonAdd, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ButtonExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonExit.setObjectName("ButtonExit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonExit, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.ButtonRemove.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Remove an album"))
        self.ButtonShowAll.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show all registerd albums"))
        self.ButtonShowSpecific.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show a specific album"))
        self.Text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome to the MusicDatabase Version 2.1-2017"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please select one of the options below."))
        self.ButtonAdd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add an album"))
        self.ButtonExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Authors: N.S. Geldorp & H. Nahumury"))
```

Comment: What is raw? What is edited? Are you editing the generated file with `pyuic`? Why? And what version doesn't work?

Comment: Raw is unedited, Yes i edited the file. Because otherwise it wont run anyways. Both versions dont.
The raw one doesnt know how to show the screen and the edited one comes with the error. and i want an fix for the edited one...

Comment: Pyuic isnt made to make converted programs run. it just generates the data of how the screen looks. further it doesnt tell the program how to run itself.

Comment: Wait, Didnt get your question right. The first code is edited, the second is the raw untouched version of exactly the same ui file

Comment: I have taken your raw code - it works without any issues for me...

Comment: okay, but does it show the screen?

Comment: Yes, it shows the GUI properly.

Comment: What?!?!? Can you send me a screenshot?

Comment: Because it does not at my end

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Qt Designer serves to generate the design of the view, pyuic5 converts that design into python code, this element must be used with logic, in addition it is recommended not to modify it.

first solution:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second Solution:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self)


import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Third solution:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)



import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```